# Is there a word for the act of "getting paid to get beat up"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests

"Prostitution" is to "selling one's body for sex" as "?" is to "Selling one's body for abuse"?

Comment: Why do you need that word? Ohhhhhh, please don't. :)

Comment: This doesn’t cover the monetary aspect of it, but do you mean something like “sparring”?  Or maybe something along the lines of “human tackling dummy”?  (You could prefix such phrases with “professional”.)  Or are you looking for something more violent and/or less controlled?

Answer (score 1):

[Masochism](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Masochism) means deriving pleasure from pain or humiliation. It’s typically paired with [sadism](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sadism). Neither explicitly cover getting paid, but I’d be interested to see if there is a word for this. If someone (a sadist) wants to pay to beat or humiliate another, I think they’d search for a particular (masochistic) kind of prostitute.